# Why is my approve() function using incorrect token_id

Tags: web3js, erc-20, erc-20-approve, liquidity-provider

I have created an ERC20 token using openzeppelin and web3. I am then trying add some of this new token to a contract (An instance of UniswapV2Router02.sol) in order to add liquidity to a liquidity pair. For some reason, when I run the approve function on my new ERC20 contract, the Ethereum explorer is confusing the amount being approved with the token id.

[image]

Here is the function I am using

`await LToken1.approve(router.address, web3.utils.toWei('0.02'));`

Am I calling the function incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you add the code of your ERC20 definition (specially the import you do from OpenZeppelin).

However, I already bet that you seem to be using an ERC721 token rather than ERC20 one (and Uniswap only accepts ERC20 or Ether). Notice that your approve function matches with [ERC721 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721):

```
function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;
```

However, you should be using the [ERC20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20):

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
```

If this is not the case, please update the question with your code and will adjust the answer accordingly.